# Add extra data to chart.js object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, chart.js, angular-chart

I am new to using chart.js or angular-charts. What I am trying to do is add extra data to the chart object that is being built so I can use it to display outside of the chart the long field names. Currently the field names are too long on the chart so we have in our object a field-name and a long-field-name. However when I build the chart object it only sends over the short labels. I want to be able to pass the long field names somehow to the chart object and reference it.

```js
$rootScope.hoverLongFieldName = function(points, evt) {
  try {
    console.log(points);
    $scope.index = points[0]['_index'];
    $rootScope.placeHolderForLongFieldName = points[0]['_view'].label;
    $scope.$apply();
  } catch (e) {}
};
```

```html
<canvas id="panel1bar" class="chart-bar" height="229px"
        chart-series="data" chart-labels="short-labels"
        chart-data="data" chart-colours="['#008080']"
        chart-hover="hoverLongFieldName" chart-legend="false" />
```

How do I add extra data to chart object that is being returned in 'points'

Comment: Which version of Chart.js are you using because there's a massive shift in API from 1.x to 2.x. In fact, 2.x was totally re-writen so you need to specify so we can see how to help you